# Direct Limits of Vector Spaces: Confusion about Definition of Mappings Given

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, category-theory

First, I give the definitions I am using for the question. They are essentially those found on the Wikipedia page concerning Direct Limits.

> Let $\{V_i\}_{i\in I}$ be a family of vector spaces in $Vec_\mathbb{F}$, where $I$ is a directed set. For each $i\le j$, let $f_{ij}:V_i\to V_j$ be a morphism satisfying the following axioms:
>
> $(1)$ $f_{ii}=Id_{V_i}$
>
> $(2)$ $f_{ik}=f_{jk}\circ f_{ij}$ for all $i\le j\le k$. The pair $(\{V_i\},\{f_{ij}\})$ is called a direct system over $I$.
>
> Let $C$ be the direct sum of the $V_i$'s:
> $$C=\bigoplus_{i\in I}V_i $$
> and let $\iota_i:V_i\to C$ be the natural inclusions of the $V_i$ into $C$. Let $D$ be the subspace of $C$ generated by elements of the form $x_i-f_{ij}(x_i)$ where $i\le j$ and $x_i\in V_i$. Let
> $$\mathbf{V}=\lim_{\to}V_i:=C/D. $$
> Let $\mu:C\to C/D$ be the quotient map and let $\mu_i=\mu\circ \iota_i:V_i\to\mathbf{V}$ be the restriction of $\mu$ to $V_i$. Since $D$ depends on the maps $\{f_{ij}\}$, so do $C/D$ and the maps $\{\mu_i\}$. The pair $(\mathbf{V},\{\mu_i\}_{i\in I})$ is called the **Direct Limit** of the system $(\{V_i\}_{i\in I},\{f_{ij}\}_{i\le j\in I}).$

Now that that is out of the way, the question I have been struggling with is the following:

**Question:** Show that each $[v]\in \mathbf{V}$ can be written as $[v]=\mu_i(v_i)$ for some $i\in I$ and $v_i\in V_i$.

**Attempt:** Let's assume $[v]$ is the equivalence class of some $v_i\in V_i$, one of the vector spaces in the direct summation. We can write this as $[v_i]$. Then, it is true by *definition* that $\mu_i(v_i)=[v_i]$.

Now, what if we have $v=v_i+v_j+v_k$, for $v_i\in V_i, v_j\in V_j, v_k\in V_k$, for $i\le j\le k\in I$. The enticing thing to do is to consider the morphisms $\mu_k:V_k\to C/D$. Because $V_k$ is the farthest along in the system, we can consider
$$\mu_k(v_{k'})=\mu_k(f_{ik}(v_i)+f_{jk}(v_j)+f_{kk}(v_k))=[v].$$
This construction should work for any such vector $v$, we just need to use the properties of a directed set to find $\ell\in I$ such that $\ell$ is $\ge$ than the rest of the indices of the vector spaces used in "creating" the element.

**Thoughts:** Truth be told I'm not certain about that attempt, but I suppose my confusion arises from how these $\{\mu_i\}$ can be made to act on elements of $V_i\oplus V_j\oplus V_k$, if not in this manner.

Comment: I think you have the idea.  I would spell out the details a bit more.  For example, the properties of directed sets give you what you need for *finite* sets, that that is all you need is due to the properties of direct sums.  It's not too hard to write out the general form of the example you gave, i.e. to spell out "this construction". As for what for what you say in "Thoughts", you have $\mu(\sum f_{ik}(v_i))$. All those $f_{ik}(v_i)$ are in the $V_k$ component and every vector in the $V_k$ component is $\iota_k(v)$ for some $v$ so you have $\mu(\iota_k(v)) = \mu_k(v)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An official answer after six years? Why not, it is nice to have a reference in this forum.

Let us first observe that

> Let $D$ be the subspace of $C$ generated by elements of the form $x_i-f_{ij}(x_i)$ where $i\le j$ and $x_i\in V_i$

is imprecise. The formally correct definition is

> Let $D$ be the subspace of $C$ generated by elements of the form $\iota_i(x_i)-\iota_j(f_{ij}(x_i))$ where $i\le j$ and $x_i\in V_i$.

For $i \le j$ we have
$$\mu_j \circ f_{ij} = \mu_i \tag{1} .$$
In fact, for $v_i \in V_i$ we have $\mu_i(v_i) = [\iota_i(v_i)]$ and $(\mu_j \circ f_{ij})(v_i) = [\iota_j(f_{ij}(v_i))]$ so that $\mu_i(v_i) - (\mu_j \circ f_{ij})(v_i) = [\iota_i(v_i) - \iota_j(f_{ij}(v_i))] = 0$, i.e. $(\mu_j \circ f_{ij})(v_i) = \mu_i(v_i)$.

Now let $[v] \in \mathbf V$. The element $v \in C$ has the form $v = (v_i)_{i \in I}$ with $v_i \in V_i$ and all but finitely many $v_i = 0$.

If $v = 0$, we have $[v] =  \mu_i(0)$ for each $i$.

If $v \ne 0$, let $i_1,\ldots,i_n$ be the indices such that $v_{i_k} \ne 0$. Then $v = \sum_{k=1}^n \iota_{i_k}(v_{i_k})$. Since $I$ is directed, we find $r \in I$ such that $i_k \le r$ for all $k$. Using $\text{(1)}$  we get
$$[v] = \sum_{k=1}^n \mu_{i_k}(v_{i_k}) =  \sum_{k=1}^n \mu_r(f_{i_k r}(v_{i_k})) = \mu_r\left(\sum_{k=1}^n f_{i_k r}(v_{i_k})\right) = \mu_r(v_r)$$
with $v_r =  \sum_{k=1}^n f_{i_k r}(v_{i_k}) \in V_r$.

Note that an alternative construction of the direct limit can be found in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_limit) wikipedia article.